# Request Timeout error while calling in PJSIP 2.6

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip, ndk-build

I have build PjSip 2.6 for android and I am getting some error during call.Here my sip registration is working fine and getting 200 response code both of the side.

When I try to call from my pJsua2 sample app that time getting below error From logcat log, I am getting 200 response code for call but still I can not get any response at backed side (On backend side,I have setup asterisk version 13.9.1)

I am using NDK version android-ndk-r10d  and had build pjsip for all architecture So If any one have idea then Please do need full

```
Buddy Uri : sip:2222@192.168.1.xx:5060
11-24 15:00:33.303 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out:       15:00:33.302   pjsua_call.c !Making call with acc #0 to sip:2222@192.168.1.xx:5060
11-24 15:00:33.303 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.303    pjsua_aud.c  .Set sound device: capture=-1, playback=-2
11-24 15:00:33.303 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.303    pjsua_aud.c  ..Opening sound device (speaker + mic) PCM@16000/1/20ms
11-24 15:00:33.303 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.303 android_jni_de  ...Creating Android JNI stream
11-24 15:00:33.304 1272-1350/system_process W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
11-24 15:00:33.306 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.306 android_jni_de  ...Using audio input source : 7
11-24 15:00:33.307 938-938/? E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
11-24 15:00:33.308 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.308 android_jni_de  ...Audio record initialized successfully.
11-24 15:00:33.309 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.309 android_jni_de  ...Audio track initialized successfully.
11-24 15:00:33.309 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.309   ec0xb3f1d600  ...Creating AEC
11-24 15:00:33.309 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.309          speex  ...warning: Unknown speex_preprocess_ctl request: : 2
11-24 15:00:33.309 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.309   ec0xb3f1d600  ...AEC created, clock_rate=16000, channel=1, samples per frame=320, tail length=200 ms, latency=0 ms
11-24 15:00:33.309 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.309 android_jni_de  ...Android JNI stream started
11-24 15:00:33.309 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.309  dlg0xb3ca5064  .UAC dialog created
11-24 15:00:33.309 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.309  dlg0xb3ca5064  ..Session count inc to 2 by mod-pjsua
11-24 15:00:33.309 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.309  pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: initializing media..
11-24 15:00:33.309 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.309        icetp00  ..Creating ICE stream transport with 2 component(s)
11-24 15:00:33.309 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.309 stuntp0xa3dcfe  ...SO_RCVBUF set to 163840
11-24 15:00:33.309 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.309 stuntp0xa3dcfe  ...SO_SNDBUF set to 163840
11-24 15:00:33.310 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.310        icetp00  ...Comp 1: srflx candidate (tpid=64) starts Binding discovery
11-24 15:00:33.310 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.310 stuntp0xa3dcfe  .....TX 36 bytes STUN message to 139.162.62.29:3478:
11-24 15:00:33.310 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: --- begin STUN message ---
11-24 15:00:33.310 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: STUN Binding request
11-24 15:00:33.310 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out:  Hdr: length=16, magic=2112a442, tsx_id=104cef1313b811da00017288
11-24 15:00:33.310 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out:  Attributes:
11-24 15:00:33.310 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out:   SOFTWARE: length=12, value="pjnath-2.6.0"
11-24 15:00:33.310 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: --- end of STUN message ---
11-24 15:00:33.310 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.310 utsx0xb3f7174c  .....STUN client transaction created
11-24 15:00:33.310 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.310 utsx0xb3f7174c  .....STUN sending message (transmit count=1)
11-24 15:00:33.311 20190-21761/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.311 android_jni_de !Playback thread started
11-24 15:00:33.312 20190-21759/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.312 android_jni_de !Recorder thread started
11-24 15:00:33.312 938-21758/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xb5d5f000 ready to run
11-24 15:00:33.314 20190-21759/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.314 android_jni_de  Setting thread priority successful
11-24 15:00:33.315 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.315        icetp00 !...Comp 1/1: host candidate 10.0.2.15:54458 (tpid=64) added
11-24 15:00:33.315 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.315 stuntp0xa3c6df  ...SO_RCVBUF set to 163840
11-24 15:00:33.315 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.315 stuntp0xa3c6df  ...SO_SNDBUF set to 163840
11-24 15:00:33.315 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.315        icetp00  ...Comp 2: srflx candidate (tpid=64) starts Binding discovery
11-24 15:00:33.315 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.315 stuntp0xa3c6df  .....TX 36 bytes STUN message to 139.162.62.29:3478:
11-24 15:00:33.315 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: --- begin STUN message ---
11-24 15:00:33.315 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: STUN Binding request
11-24 15:00:33.315 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out:  Hdr: length=16, magic=2112a442, tsx_id=20477f6a351d6ae80001cd5f
11-24 15:00:33.315 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out:  Attributes:
11-24 15:00:33.315 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out:   SOFTWARE: length=12, value="pjnath-2.6.0"
11-24 15:00:33.315 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: --- end of STUN message ---
11-24 15:00:33.315 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.315 utsx0xb3f76b4c  .....STUN client transaction created
11-24 15:00:33.315 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.315 utsx0xb3f76b4c  .....STUN sending message (transmit count=1)
11-24 15:00:33.316 20190-21761/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.316 android_jni_de !Setting thread priority successful
11-24 15:00:33.317 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.317        icetp00 !...Comp 2/1: host candidate 10.0.2.15:45219 (tpid=64) added
11-24 15:00:33.317 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.317        icetp00  ...ICE stream transport 0xb3fda414 created
11-24 15:00:33.317 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.317        icetp00  ...ICE init update: comp 1/0[srflx] is pending
11-24 15:00:33.317 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.317        icetp01  ..Creating ICE stream transport with 2 component(s)
11-24 15:00:33.317 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.317 stuntp0xa3c6f2  ...SO_RCVBUF set to 163840
11-24 15:00:33.317 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.317 stuntp0xa3c6f2  ...SO_SNDBUF set to 163840
11-24 15:00:33.317 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.317        icetp01  ...Comp 1: srflx candidate (tpid=64) starts Binding discovery
11-24 15:00:33.317 20190-20190/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app I/System.out: 15:00:33.317 stuntp0xa3c6f2  .....TX 36 bytes STUN message to 139.162.62.29:3478:
```

Comment: did u solve it??

Comment: no not yet.. but if u find any solution then please share here. Thanks

Comment: where the response for 200 OK was not generated? In Android Application side or server side?

Comment: In server side no logs for 200 response

Comment: still stuck on the same?